# 'price_and_currency' method in Python's Amazon Simple Product API returns "Decimal"

Tags: python, amazon-product-api

I'm calling the Amazon Product API using Amazon Simple Product API Module (Python):

```
product = amazon.lookup(ItemId="B00H2VOSP8")
```

When returning `return str(product.price_and_currency)` I get the following:

```
(Decimal('149.95'), 'USD')
```

The official [documentation](https://github.com/yoavaviram/python-amazon-simple-product-api) indicates I should be getting `('149.95', 'USD')`

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 0):

It's a tuple. I've accessed the first value and converted it to string like 
this:

`str(product.price_and_currency[0])`

Which equals to `149.95`, of course.